# Best practice to return different data in Web Api 2 with HTTP Accept Header

Tags: c#, rest, http-headers, asp.net-web-api2, formatter

We have a Web Api 2 project with the following route:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    // GET /accounts/search?name={name}`
    public PagedSearchResult<SimpleAccount> Search(AccountSearchRequest parameters)
    {
        // Repository paged search logic here
    }

    // GET /accounts/{id}
    public SimpleAccount Get(int id)
    {
        // Repository get here
    }
}
```

Normally this methods returns a simplified account, with just an Id and a Name, but for different apps, we want to extend that data. Therefor we use a custom http accept header (`Accept: application/vnd.ourapplication.account+json`) to extend the `SimpleAccount` to an AppSpecificAccount.
To do this we've created an AppSpecificAccountFormatter:

```
public class AppSpecificAccountFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public AccountFormatter (Container container)
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.ourapplication.account+json"));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return (type == typeof(PagedSearchResult<SimpleAccount>) || type == typeof(SimpleAccount));
    }

    public override void WriteToStream(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, System.Text.Encoding effectiveEncoding)
    {
        if (type == typeof (PagedSearchResult<SimpleAccount>))
        {
            // Extend logic here (with lots of db access, per result)
            value = ExtendValue(value);
            type = typeof(AppSpecificAccount);
        }
        else if (type == typeof (SimpleAccount))
        {
            // Extend logic here (with lots of db access)
            value = ExtendValue(value);
            type = typeof(AppSpecificAccount);
        }

        base.WriteToStream(type, value, writeStream, effectiveEncoding);
    }
}
```

As you can guess this is not a desired situation with the database accessing in the formatter. We want to honor the REST principles with a GET on `/account/1` should always return the same entity, and with the accept header we can change the format.

Is this the way to do this? or should we do the split in the Controller?

Comment: IMO this should be the way to do it. Serialization should take care of what you are returning in you response.